# How to set a special rule in an array?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, typescript

I have an array and a counter, which is matched with the array.

What I need is a sequence with the following attributes:
When the counter reaches x6, the first 5 items should be set false.
When the counter reaches x11, the first 10 items should be set false.
So then only 5 items are set to true at once in sequences.

```
//in .ts for reference
//Counter, which is matched with the array - they are then saved:
this.counter+=1;
var xNum="x"+this.counter;
this.x[xNum] = true;

//Array of items to infinite
public x : any = ["x0", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6",
  "x7", "x8", "x9", "x10", "x11", "x12",
  "x13", "x14", "x15", "x16", "x17", "x18"...]
```

Comment: `this.x[xNum] = true;` will be a misuse of arrays as you are essentially using a plain object but it has the array prototype for not good reason

Comment: well, that part actually works - my question is about how you would set up the sequence rule.

Comment: a few pointers:
1. dont make the array type any.
2. dont set properties (this.x[xNum] = true) on an array, use a separate object {} for that
3. Your description does not make sense. The last thing about only 5 items contradicts the 10 items mentioned above.

Comment: How does the counter increment?

Comment: Why can't I make the array type "any"?
Why should I declare the status with {} within the array?
"The last thing about only 5 items contradicts the 10 items mentioned above." - 
Please read the above written again.

Comment: @Balints an array with type `any` *is not an array*. If it was, you'd have defined it as `Array`. The reason you don't want to use an array for non-array uses should be fairly self-evident but here you go - you aren't using an array, yet you define it as such. What you do is you're using a *plain object* and yet instantiate an array to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like this:

```
if(counter >= 5 && counter % 5 === 0){
  for(let i = this.counter - 5; i < counter; i++){
    const xNum = "x"+this.counter;
    this.x[xNum] = false;
  }
}
```